to call or to be calling (what's the differnce between 'to call' and 'to be calling'?)

It's not very nice to call teachers by the first name.


It's not very nice to be calling teachers by the first name.

What's the difference between them? The second one is grammatical? (The versions with the dummy 'it' removed are below.)

To call teachers by the first name is not very nice.


To be calling teachers by the first name is not very nice.

I feel the "To be calling here" is awkward because we can write "Calling teachers by the first name is not very nice."

"Is the second one grammatical?"  The continuous tense implies that it is a habit; the first sentence could refer to doing it only once (though it doesn't have to).

I'd use the possessive their as in by their first names.  That aside, the examples are grammatical and mean the same, although I also find example 4 clumsy.
The extraposed ones sound more natural.  Also, the main message not very nice is in front and has more impact.

The choice of the singular (name) or plural (names) is really just a matter of preference (although you imply this yourself). It's an example of situations where both serve the purpose. If, for example, five people are each showing one dog in a competition, it would be fine to use either construction: "Will all the contestants now kindly bring their dog(s) forward". Or: "Will each pupil (all pupils) now raise their right hand."

Thanks, @Ronald Sole.  Agreed.

The usual difference between the simple present (states that are always true) and the progressive (actions that are ongoing in the present)
The simple present version talks about a general rule.  The progressive might be used to address a child concerning their behaviour right now.
Of course, you address a child concerning their behaviour right now by stating a general rule... so ultimately there isn't really much difference. Generally, the simple present would be preferred in most cases, it is simpler and feels more formal.

Now, Class 1, at school we have some rules.  There is no running in the corridor. We are quiet when we are working, and it isn't nice to call teachers by their first name, so we use Mr or Mrs.


Now Jonny,  I heard you say, "Hey Peter, I like your socks!" to Mr Jones. It isn't nice to be calling teachers by their first name, so remember to say "Mr Jones" or "Sir" in the future.

